# Google Maps API modifying page styles after loading only in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am running into a strange issue. I load a page and initially the text on the whole page has an opacity of 1. Google Maps API is set to load on a timeout. After 2 seconds, the maps API loads the map, and the page styles all the sudden are modified. It's like the text on the page has been reduced in opacity ( see photos ). This issue only seems to be affecting me in Safari. Has anyone run into something similar or know of an issue or what may be causing this?

The Original Before The Map Has Loaded

[image: Original - Before Maps is Loaded]

After The Map Has Loaded

[image: After The Map Has Loaded]

Comment: I'm guessing there is too much code for a jsFiddle, but can you at least provide a link to the site you are experiencing this on?   I'd like to take a look and see what the behavior is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not a change in opacity, but a change in font smoothing. Safari may change the font smoothing when there are visible `position: fixed;` elements on the page.

### Explanation

When `-webkit-font-smoothing` is not specified, Safari will use `subpixel-antialiased` as the default value for most of the elements and the text would be rendered like this:

[image]

However, when it encounters a visible `position:fixed` element on the page, it may use `antialiased` for font smoothing, which looks like this:

[image]

### Demo

You can check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4e4x/)** (on Safari only) and play with the controls to see how `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `position` affect text appearance on Safari.

### Solution

To prevent Safari from changing font smoothing, just specify the `font-smoothing` as follows:

```css
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Whoah. I never thought specifying `subpixel-antialiased` would actually force Safari to use it. I thought it was just a bug in Safari **not being able** to use subpixel antialiasing with transforms. I was going to downvote you thinking you were just going to suggest [using `antialiased`](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/), instead you are awesome.

Comment: Wow! Awesome! I don't even know what to say, but you are a life saver. I would have never come up with that. I have spent hours on this issue. Sorry for the delayed response, I truthfully didn't think anyone would respond to this question. So far I have not noticed any effect on performance, but do you think this might have an effect on performance. Applying font-smoothing to the whole page that is. Thanks again! This is huge!!!

Comment: @mcbeav Safari has always been applying font-smoothing to the whole page. In fact, this is central to Mac OS where the text on most of the programs have been smoothened. You can test it with `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;` to see how the page looks like without font-smoothing. In other words, don't worry about the performance impact.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help! This is huge! Thank you for sharing your knowledge and time.