# Font issue on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, safari, supersized

I have an issue with the font on Safari on this website ([vincentmorin.com](http://vincentmorin.com/)). If you click on the icon on the top right of the screen you'll see that the font in the dropdown menu looks weird (thin and blurry).

[image]

I think that the issue is caused by the Supersized JS plugin. If you look on another page where the Supersized plugin is not called (ex: [vincentmorin.com/Tour](http://vincentmorin.com/Tour/)), the menu looks fine.

[image]

Also see here: [vincentmorin.com/*dev*](http://vincentmorin.com/_dev_/) you can see that issue is occuring only when the first slide is loaded. Weird!

Someone knows what is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any difference on my macbook pro retina.

Comment: Hi, it's weird. I edited the post with pictures to show you. I validated the issue on both macbook pro with retina and ipad air.

Comment: BTW, I see same issue in Safari non-retina, albeit in both Chrome & Firefox on MacBook Air everything looks as on your 2nd screenshot.

Comment: @nilfalse Thanks, it looks like you're right. I was sure it was only on retina! It's looks like it's Safari related. I've edited the post.

Comment: I don't even see it in Safari, retina or not. Comparison screenshots showing both pages in chrome and safari on my [retina display](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gH4Yb.jpg) and my [non-retina display](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J7gPC.png).

Comment: The issue is also visible on Chrome/Ipad, where I took the screenshots.

Comment: @gilly3 Wow how come is this possible. Maybe an OS setting?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I was not able to mitigate it. It only happens in OS desktop sierra/high sierra, macbooks or iOS seems unaffected. I'd be glad if you have any suggestions, the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887647/font-rendering-blurry-on-safari-mac-os-10-11)

Answer (score 11):

### Safari on Mac

This problem occurs because you have a visible `position:fixed` element on the page, and Safari would change the font smoothing to `antialiased`, making the text look thin and blurry.

> #### Exhibit 1
>
> Visible `position:fixed` element causing text to look thin.
>   [image]

> #### Exhibit 2
>
> Hide the element and the text become normal again.
>   [image]

To fix this, you should state the font smoothing explicitly as follows:

```css
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

> #### Exhibit 3
>
> Applying the fix and the issue is gone.
>   [image]

For more information on how `position:fixed` affects `-webkit-font-smoothing`, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19925121/1493698).

### Safari on iOS

On iOS devices however, Safari would blindly apply `antialiased` to text even when `-webkit-font-smoothing` is set to be `subpixel-antialiased` and there are no visible `position:fixed` elements on the page. To correct for this, you can use `-webkit-text-stroke` to approximate the looks of the text.

```css
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;
```

> #### Exhibit 4
>
> Thin and blurry text on iPad.
>   [image]

> #### Exhibit 5
>
> Use `-webkit-text-stroke` to simulate the original looks of the text.
>   [image]

Comment: Hi, it seems to work well on your device and on many others regarding your answer to the other question. I applied the fix on [vincentmorin.com](http://vincentmorin.com) but it didn't work. I can test it only on ipad air (retina) however, may you tell me if it looks OK on your device. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, Safari on iOS ignores `-webkit-font-smoothing` and blindly applies `antialiased` to text even in [a very simple page](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qmkMC/1/show/). When I run it on the simulators, not even your tour page or dev page look fine (eg. [iPhone](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EnrsC.jpg), [iPad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6esmC.jpg)). I tested it on Mac, iPad simulator and iPhone, and the only device where this fix works is the Mac. Can you give me an example where the text looks normal on an iOS device?

Comment: Given the device discrepancy, you would have to hack it using `-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;` on iOS devices. Here is what it looks like on the iPad simulator [with](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pCTCk.jpg) and [without](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gRHMH.jpg) the `text-stroke`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. So the **-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;** fix works for desktop Mac and **-webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px;** seems to work on my Ipad retina. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: I tried with no success, see here: http://vincentmorin.com/_dev_/ also you can see that issue is occuring only when the first slide is loaded. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is changing the font to any web font. Your "v_helv" font is not well supported on safari / chrome. There are a lot of free cross compatible browser font on [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Otherwise, you can change the font type if the web page is openned on web kit browser type by using this code:

```
@media all -webkit-device-pixel-ratio {
    body{
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light" !important;
        font-weight: 200
    }
}
@media not -webkit-device-pixel-ratio {
    body{font-family: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" !important;}
}
```

Comment: Hi, (v_helv is just the name I gave to Helvetica font) the font is perfect on every other pages except the homepage, which has Supersized JS plugin. Look here: http://vincentmorin.com/_dev_/ and you'll see that the font is OK until the first slide appears.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the font problem. I had experience same problem with you in the past. I have editted my answer.  I reckon HelveticaNeue-UltraLight is not well supported on webkit browser

Comment: Hi, so basically you tell me that I must use HelveticaNeue-Light instead of HelveticaNeue-UltraLight?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think HelveticaNeue-UltraLight is well rendered on Firefox, but not on Webkit browser (Chrome & Safari). If you're using "HelveticaNeue-Light", you can change the thickness of character by using "font-weight" property, put it below 400 (400 is normal). Other people who don't have this problem, probably they have installed the raw font on their operating system.

Comment: @EldwinEldwin: I have a similar issue with the Raleway font but switching to Helvetica or Arial did not remove the problem. The text in a `position:fixed` element is either abnormally thin or aliased (when I add `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` to the `body`).

Comment: Hi @ArnaudRenaud, please post new question with more description including the link of your website preview, so I can inspect it furthermore and try to give you the answer.